# How to useEffect when value in localStorage changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

In my react app i'm saving user data filters into localStorage. I want to useEffect, when that data was changed. How to correctly trigger that effect? I tried this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (rawEstateObjects.length && localStorage.activeEstateListFilter) {
      const activeFilter = JSON.parse(localStorage.activeEstateListFilter)
      if (activeFilter.length) {
        applyFilter(activeFilter)
      }
    }
  }, [rawEstateObjects, localStorage.activeEstateListFilter])
```

but `localStorage.activeEstateListFilter` doesn't triggers the effect..

Comment: did you try to set value of the localStorage in state then use that state variable ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-pascal-kjt8r

Answer (score 0):

did you set value in localStorge?
if set it then:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function activeEstateList() {
    const item = localStorage.getItem('activeEstateListFilter')

    if (rawEstateObjects.length && item) {
      const activeFilter = JSON.parse(localStorage.activeEstateListFilter)
      if (activeFilter.length) {
        applyFilter(activeFilter)
      }
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('storage', activeEstateList)

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('storage', activeEstateList)
  }
}, [])
```

refrence answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178371/7962191