# Navbar not updating after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title says my navbar is not changing the fragments after updating the state. I have no idea how to refresh it and other ideas seems to not work for me. I have tried to change the statements.
All i want to do is, after a user logs in successfully the state changes to true and the navbar updates with the corrent components. Thank you !

Home.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

function Home() {
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!localStorage.getItem("loggedIn")){
            localStorage.setItem("loggedIn",false);
        }
    },[]);
    return (
        <div>
        Home
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

function Login() {
    const[username,setUsername] = useState('');
    const[password,setPassword] = useState('');
    const[errorMessage,setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    let history = useHistory();

    const login = () =>{
        console.log(username);
        Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/user/login",{username: username,password: password}).then((response) => {
            //console.log(response);
            if(response.data.loggedIn){
                localStorage.setItem("loggedIn",true);
                localStorage.setItem("username",response.data.username);
                history.push('/');
            }else{
                setErrorMessage(response.data.message);
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="Login">
        <h1>Login to your BugTrack account !</h1>
        <div className="LoginForm">
            
            <input type="text" placeholder="USERNAME" 
            onChange={(event)=>{setUsername(event.target.value)}}/>

            <input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD"
            onChange={(event)=>{setPassword(event.target.value)}}/>

            <button onClick={login}>Login to you account</button>
            <h1 style={{color: "red"}}>{errorMessage}</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login
```

Navbar.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';

function Navbar() {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    useEffect(()=> {
        setLoggedIn(localStorage.getItem("loggedIn"));
    },[localStorage.getItem("loggedIn")]);

    return (
        <div className="Navbar">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            {!loggedIn ? (
                <Fragment>
                    <a href="profile">Profile</a>
                </Fragment>
            ):(
                <Fragment>
                    <a href="/register">Register</a>
                    <a href="/login">Login</a>
                </Fragment>
            )}
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: you cannot rerender component using `localsrotage` in `useEffect`, you should use Context API [https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html] for this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to to use `localStorage` as a useEffect dependency which isn't supports for React to rerender/update the component. Check this: [useEffect do not listen for localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178240/useeffect-do-not-listen-for-localstorage) - it's like duplicate of your question.