# How to render every items from local storage in ToDo App

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

> 

How do I render all the items from local storage and display them as react component after every render? I am trying to make a toDo app where I'm trying to cache the data the user types into the checkboxes.

> 

Whenever the user leaves the page and comes back, the data they typed into the checkboxes earlier is still shown. I've got this partially solved but the problem I am struggling here is not being able to display all the items from local storage as react components within the useEffect. What are good solutions to solve this problem?

```
**Tasks.JSX**
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
    import {Delete, Refresh, Add} from "../components/Actions";
    import {Header} from "../components/Header";
    import {PriorityLists} from "../components/PriorityLists";
    import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
    import { serialize, deserialize } from "react-serialize";
    
    

    function Task() {
       
    
      
        const [toDo, setToDo] = useState([])
        const [idsToRefresh, setIdsToRefresh] = useState([]);
        const [filter_items, setFilterItems] = useState(false);
        const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);
       
        const [text, setTextValue] = useState({key:null, txt:null});
    
        useEffect(()=> {
            for(let i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                let storedValue = localStorage.key(i);
                let value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storedValue));
                if(typeof value === "string") {
                    setToDo(toDo.concat({_Id: storedValue, item_value: <PriorityLists id = {storedValue} checked = {false} addIds = {addIds} local_storage ={ls} text_value = {value} />}));
                    console.log(`${value} Index ${i}`);
                }
                    
                
                
               
            }
        }, [])
    
    
    
        
        useEffect(() => {
            if(toDo[0] !== undefined) {
                setToDo(toDo.filter(item=> {
                    return !ids.includes(item._Id);
                }))
               
            }
    
    
        }, [filter_items]);
    
        function addIds(checked, id_to_be_deleted) {
            if(!checked) {
                setIds((item)=> [...item, id_to_be_deleted]);
            }
            else {
                setIds(ids.filter(item=> {
                    return item !== id_to_be_deleted;
                }))
            }
        }
        
        function ls(e) {
            localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(e.target.id), serialize(e.target.value));
            
        }
    
        
    
    
    
        function addToDos() {
            const id = uuidv4();
         
            setToDo(toDo.concat({_Id: id, item_value: <PriorityLists id = {id} checked = {false} addIds = {addIds} local_storage ={ls} text_value = {null} />}));
            setIdsToRefresh(idsToRefresh.concat(id));
       
        }
    
      
        
    
        function refresh() {
            setToDo(toDo.filter(item=> {
                return !idsToRefresh.includes(item._Id);
            }))
        }
    
    
    
        return (
        <div className = "main-content">
            <div className = "container-fluid">
                <div className = "row underline">
                    <div className= "col">
                        <div className = "row">
                        <div className = "col-3 pt-2">
                            <Refresh _refresh = {refresh} />
                        </div>
    
                        <div className = "col-6 text-center">
                            <Header header ={"Tasks"}/>
                        </div>
    
                        <div className = "col-3 pt-2">
                            <button  className = "float-right">
                                <Delete setFilterItems = {setFilterItems} filter = {filter_items} />
                            </button>
                        </div>
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div className = "row">
                    <div className = "col">
              
                       {
                       
                       
                       toDo.map(item=> {
                           return (<div key = {item._Id}> 
                           <ul>
                               <li>{item.item_value}</li>
                             
                           </ul>
                           </div>)
                       })}
                        
                       
     
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
    
    
                <div className = "row">
                    
                    <div className = "col pr-4">
            
                        <Add addToDos = {addToDos} />
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
    
    
    
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        )
    }
    
    export default Task;
```

**PriorityLists.jsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { Priority } from "./Actions";




function PriorityLists(props) {
    const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const [changeInput, setChangeInput] = useState(props.text_value);



    function check(e) {
        const id_to_be_deleted = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("unique_Key").value;
       
        if(!isChecked) {
            setChecked(true);
            props.addIds(isChecked, id_to_be_deleted);

        }

        else {
            setChecked(false);
            props.addIds(isChecked, id_to_be_deleted)
        }
    }

    function setChange(e) {
        setChangeInput(e.target.value);
        props.local_storage(e);
    }

    

    return ( 
    <form key = {props.id}  >
       <div className = "input-group mb-3">
            <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <div className="input-group-text">
                <input unique_Key = {props.id}   onInput = {e=>   e.target.checked = isChecked} onClick={e=> check(e) } checked = {props.checked} id = "check-item" type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <textarea id = {props.id} onChange = {e=>setChange(e)} value = {changeInput}   class="form-control"  rows="1" name = {props.name}></textarea>
            <Priority id = {props.id} text_value = {changeInput} />
         </div>
   </form>
    )
}

export {PriorityLists};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add a listener like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function watchStorage() {
       for(let i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
          let storedValue = localStorage.key(i);
             let value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storedValue));
               if(typeof value === "string") {
                    setToDo(toDo.concat({_Id: storedValue, item_value: <PriorityLists id = {storedValue} checked = {false} addIds = {addIds} local_storage ={ls} text_value = {value} />}));
                    console.log(`${value} Index ${i}`);
                }
                    
      }

    window.addEventListener("storage", watchStorage);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage",watchStorage);
    };
  }, []);
```

Reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178371/14480038) answer

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add an event listener to the storage event which will trigger a function call every time.

Vo has mentioned a way to work with the storage event.

I would personally prefer if you loaded the data from storage on the inital mount, and stored it in a state inside a context shared across your components.

This way you can update the state directly and as a side effect, you can update the localStorage as well.

This in my opinion is a much cleaner approach.

- create `saveData` `loadData` in a utils function for localStorage
- loadData using key, and store as initState in AppContext
- share state across views.
- update the state
- add a useEffect with state, and save data whenever state is updated

I hope this solves your problem