# Saving information to localStorage, but localStorage is not saving it on refresh (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, json, local-storage

I'm creating this project, but I am having trouble learning why my code is not being saved to localStorage upon refresh. When I add stuff to the JSON file it saves properly, but when I reload all of the data from the JSON file disappears.

I have tried many different formats for loading in the information, such as adding other formats in the format string but nothing has seemed to work.

```
     const [notes, setNotes] = useState([
        ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const savedNotes = localStorage.getItem('react-notes-app-data');
        if (savedNotes != null) { setNotes(JSON.parse(savedNotes)); }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(
            'react-notes-app-data',
            JSON.stringify(notes)
        );
        setDisplayNotes(notes);
        }, [notes]);
```

Comment: I think you should add a condition `notes != null` before setting data in storage. Also, make sure whenever you modifies notes array, it should be a new array otherwise it won't trigger useEffect as object is same.

Comment: The answers here should get you working: [How to make useEffect listening to any change in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683616/how-to-make-useeffect-listening-to-any-change-in-localstorage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing your useState like this

```
let initialNotes;

try {
  initialNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('react-notes-app-data'));
catch(err) {
  initialNotes = [];
}
const [notes, setNotes] = useState(initialNotes);
```

And get rid of your entire first useEffect call. Basically there’s a logical error where you’re always setting localStorage to an empty array on load

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for your help. I'm kind of a new programmer so I was confused on what try catch is, but that fixed the issue!

Comment: Sure no problem. The purpose of the try catch here is in case the value that’s currently in localStorage can’t be parsed to JSON, ie if the value were undefined for example. The catch block is executed in the event of JSON.parse throwing an error in that case. This is handled by setting initialValue to an empty array as a sort of default value.

Answer (score 1):

Notes must be a new object to trigger the useEffect as it doesn't do deep checking.

I have created an example and tested it. It works fine. However, @ceckenrode has suggested better way.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-water-jiwi6x?file=/src/App.js