# Why useEffect get updated localstorage value after login

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks

I am trying to get a user id after login but user id updated successfully in local storage but not update to get a user id instantly in useEffect i trying to console updated user id it will only print in null after refreshing whole page it will print a console in user id but i will try to get a user id did not refresh a whole page How can i get the user id from useEffect

```
Login.js

 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await publicAPI.post("/login", {
      mobile,
      password,
    });
    localStorage.setItem("user_id", response?.user_id);
    navigate("/");
  };

AppRoutes.js

const AppRoutes = () => {
  const ui = localStorage.getItem("user_id");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ui) {
      console.log(ui);
    }
  }, [ui]);

  return (
       <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<UserLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>   
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make useEffect listening to any change in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683616/how-to-make-useeffect-listening-to-any-change-in-localstorage)

Comment: Also, `handleSubmit` is marked `async` and probably `publicAPI.post` needs to have `await`. Not sure if it is a mistake but anyway.

Comment: Actually i Adding my original code i should missing while writing a question