# React protected route not redirecting to children when authorisation finished

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes, react-router, local-storage

I'm trying to put in a layer of authentication in my protected routes and I've been doing this using the following:

```
function ProtectedRoute ({ children }) {
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
    return user.isVerifying ? (
        <p>Is loading...</p>
    ) : user.verified ? children : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

My user context is initialised with the following information:

```
{
    "user": null,
    "verified": false,
    "isVerifying": false
}
```

At the moment, the user authorisation state is checked by a function (`authUser`), inside of my `AuthContext.Provider`, that at the moment runs on every render of my components (shown below). This is an asynchronous function that makes an API call to check to see if the user JWT token stored in localStorage is valid.

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const AuthContext = createContext();

function AuthProvider({children}) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        "user": null,
        "verified": false,
        "isVerifying": true
    });

    async function authUser() {
        const userLocal = localStorage.getItem('user');

        if (userLocal) {
            const userLocalJSON = JSON.parse(userLocal);
            const verifyResponse = await verifyToken(userLocalJSON);

            if (verifyResponse) {
                setUser({"user": userLocalJSON, "verified": true, "isVerifying": false});
            } else {
                setUser({"user": userLocalJSON, "verified": false, "isVerifying": false});
            }
        }
    }

    async function verifyToken(userJSON) {
        try {
            setUser({"user": null, "verified": false, "isVerifying": true});

            // Make API call

            if (response.status === 200) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        authUser();
    }, [])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, authUser}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
export { AuthProvider };
```

Upon validating the token, the user context is then updated to `verified = true` with the information about the user. During this process, the user context `isVerifying = true` (an equivalent to `isLoading`) and gets set back to false once the API call is complete.

Now there are a few problems with this:

1. On every re-render of the DOM, the context information is set back to its defaults. Is there a way around this so that `useEffect()` only fires upon localStorage changes? I've tried implenting the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178240/useeffect-does-not-listen-for-localstorage), which adds a listener to localStorage and then triggers the useEffect when that changes. I could not get this to fire upon localStorage changes. Maybe I did something wrong (see below)?

   ```
    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('storage', authUser)

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('storage', authUser)
      }
    }, [])
   ```
2. Because the initial `isVerifying = false` and the switch to true doesn't occur before the DOM is rendered, the protected route navigates to the login page. Even after the user context is finally set, it remains on the login page. The loading page is never displayed and instead there is an instant redirection to the login page. Unfortunately, I can't set `isVerifying = true` initially as non-logged in users get stuck on the loading page.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you tried initializing isVerifying as true? That's might give you more control...

Comment: @Willow when I do this, non-logged in users remain stuck on the loading page

Comment: Could you add more context? I think I'd need to see how `authUser` works to really understand what's going wrong. It doesn't look like you have the `useEffect` tat calls it it in the same component: where is it?

Comment: @Willow I've updated the question with the code from that component.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that you said `authUser` runs on every render. However, your `useEffect` dependency is empty, so that will only run once - when `AuthProvider` is first mounted. I'm assuming `AuthProvider` is pretty high up in your rendering tree, so that should really only happen once.... What do you mean by  "runs on every render of my components"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve question 2:

Your ternary isn't quite doing what you want. It's kind of like saying "if user.isVerifying **or** !user.verified, navigate". That's not what we want.

Embedded ternaries can be tricky and I usually try to avoid them if I can. Since this component is so small, you don't need to do this with ternaries at all actually. I think this should work:

Set `isVerifying` to start out `true`. Then:

```
function ProtectedRoute ({ children }) {
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (user.isVerifying) {
        return <p>Is loading...</p>
    }

    if (user.verified === false) {
        return <Navigate to="/login" />
    }

    return children

}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

EDIT: You also need to update the verification state in `authUser`. Noticed how you are only updating the loading state if `userLocal` is truthy. Best bet is to start out loading, and always call setUser at the end. This isn't the only way to do it but I think it should work:

```js
    async function authUser() {
        setUser(currentState => {...currentState, isVerifying: true})
        const userLocal = localStorage.getItem('user');
        
        if (!userLocal) {
            setUser({
                user: null,
                verified: false,
                isVerifying: false,
            })
        }

        const userLocalJSON = JSON.parse(userLocal);
        const verifyResponse = await verifyToken(userLocalJSON);
        setUser({
            user: userLocalJSON,
            verified: verifyResponse,
            isVerifying: false,
        })
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like you have an issue with `authUser` as well. Will update my response.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are setting `user.user` to `userLocalJSON` even if the `verifyResponse` is false, but didn't want to change that if you weren't expecting. If that's a mistake, consider: `user: verifyResponse ? userLocalJSON : null`

Comment: Thank you for your clear and thoughtful answer! Your point about setting `user.user` to `userLocalJSON` in that situation is very valid. I think it makes more sense to do it like that - I hadn't planned to do anything else with that at this point.