# How do i re-run useEffect hook if the localstorage value has been changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, use-effect

I'm trying to re-run the useEffect hook based if any new item has been added to the localstorage.

My useEffect looks like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
      //getting all localstorage items and setting to a variable
      const localStorageItems = { ...localStorage }

      // filtering out the localstorage items for keys that only starts with "HTTP" & pushing it to the state called "testData" using setTestData useState hook.
    
      const filteredByKey = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(localStorageItems).filter(([key, value]) => {
          if (key.startsWith("http")) {
            testArr2.push({ urls: [key, value] })
            // setTestData({ urls: [key, value] })
            setTestData((prev) => [...prev, { key, value }])
          }
        })
      )
    }, [])
```

My problem is when I hit a button(adding a new data) this useEffect should ideally re-run, setting the latest data to the "testData" state.

The Problem :

- I cannot pass `window.localstorage` to the useEffect's array dependency list, as it is external variable I believe and react doesn't allow it.

What I have tried:

- I have looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178240/useeffect-does-not-listen-for-localstorage) on SO, but my situation is a bit complex as I'm loading the entire items to a variable first(I'm not aware of any better alternatives)
- I have tried to put the state value in the dependency list, but it doesn't work and goes to infinite loop.

Please help.
Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: The SO answer you link to should work for your case.  It simply sets up a listener for local storage changing (which is what you want), and only sets that listener up on the first render of your component (the empty dependency array of useState make it only run on the first render).

Comment: ```
useEffect(() => {
    function checkUserData() {
      const localStorageItems = { ...localStorage }
      if (localStorageItems) {
        const filteredByKey = Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(localStorageItems).filter(([key, value]) => {
            if (key.startsWith("http")) {
              testArr2.push({ urls: [key, value] })
              // setTestData({ urls: [key, value] })
              setTestData((prev) => [...prev, { key, value }])
            }
          })
        )
      }}window.addEventListener("storage", checkUserData)
  }, [])
```

Comment: @elunomas I did it as above but it doesn't render for the very time even

Comment: Can you share more of your code?  The useEffect hook will run exactly 1 time -- on first render -- if you include the empty dependency array. (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)
If your code is not rendering even once, then you'd need to share more of your code before we could say what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

i can give you a work around for this use case, create react context that syncs with `localStorage`. you can use the context as a `useEffect` dependency. sync means, take the value from `localStorage` at starting and update the context along with the `localStorage` from your app.

Answer (score 0):

Define a state that holds the local storage value and pass it as a useEffect parameter.

```
const [localStorageData, setLocalStorageData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    // Your codes

}, [localStorageData])
```

Comment: This wont work, i need to re-trigger `const localStorageItems = { ...localStorage }` for that, but how do i do that(same issue)

Comment: anshul this might work for you if you implemented setLocalStorageData wherever you are updating the localstorage in your code.
But @Serkan, while this might work, it seems redundant to create a copy of localstorage simply to watch for localstorage to change, doesn't it? Then anshul will need to write the _set_ function anywhere localstorage is being modified.  A much cleaner solution is just to set an event listener for localstorage to change, as in the SO answer already linked to in the question.

Answer (score -1):

you can use 'storage' event listener

```js
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
  if (e.newValue) {
    console.log('new data is saved ...')
    // ...... your code
  }
})
```