# How can I show/hide element depending on visibility of another element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, responsive

I am trying to fix a bug on the website I am building, on responsive version of it. There are two "bars" in the upper side of website - the upper one with major tabs, and the lower is with icons specific for chosen tab.

When I am changing screen size (as if to test I were using mobile), both tabs appear as small squares (as should).

Again, clicking on upper square will show a list of tabs, and clicking on lower one will show a list of icons. Clicking a second time, hides relevant list. The problem is, that if both are clicked, then both lists appear and positioned one upon another.

What I want to do, that if icon list is shown, then tab list should be hidden and vice-versa.

Now, both elements have "onClick" function that changes relevant variable\prop and show\hide itself. But how to "load" this value on another element?

How it is built: I have the "main" tsx file, which holds both tabs and icons elements.

In main file:

```
        <TabsMobile
          tab={tab}
          setTab={setTab}
          setPages={setPages}           
        /> 

 {<AdditionalMobile/>}
```

TabsMobile is for tabs, AdditionalMobile is for icons.

TabsMobile file:

```
   interface ITabsMobile {
      TabsArray: Array<Type>;
      tab: number;
      setTab: (value: number) => void;
      setPages?: any;
    }
    
    interface Type {
      page: number;
      title: string;
    }
    
    export const TabsMobile: FC<ITabsMobile> = ({
      TabsArray,
      tab,
      setTab,
      setPages
    }) => {
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    
      function updateOpen()
      {
          var openString : string = !open == true ? "true" : "false";      
          localStorage.setItem("mainTabOpen", openString);
          console.log('Inside: '+localStorage.getItem("mainTabOpen"));    
          setOpen(!open);
      }
    
      return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          <div className={styles.head} onClick={() => updateOpen()}>
            <p>Upper tabs</p>
          </div>
          {open && (
            <div className={styles.body}>
              {TabsArray.map((item: any, index) => (
                <TabsItem
                key={index}
                title={item.title}
                page={index}
                tab={tab}
                setTab={setTab}
                pages={index}
                setPages={setPages}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Now, as I understand to make AdditionalMobile hidden or invisible I need to do something like this in main file:

```
{isMainTabShown && <AdditionalMobile/>}
```

If "isMainTabShown" is true, then the element will be shown.

But, I for now, didn't find a way to:

1. Transfer variable from "TabsMobile" to main file
2. "Reload" this line of code: `{isMainTabShown && <AdditionalMobile/>}`

I tried two things, but didn't succeed. Help me with either of those, or if there is a better solution, please share it:

1. Use "localStorage"

   ```
      var openString : string = !open == true ? "true" : "false";      
      localStorage.setItem("mainTabOpen", openString);
   ```

This does indeed updates the relevant variable, but how I can "reload" it in main file?

I tried using useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
     console.log('Outside: '+localStorage.getItem("mainTabOpen"));
 }, []);
```

and also like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
     console.log('Outside: '+localStorage.getItem("mainTabOpen"));
 }, [localStorage.getItem("mainTabOpen")]);
```

But the code doesn't even seem to enter those functions.

I also tried solution from here:
[useEffect does not listen for localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178240/useeffect-does-not-listen-for-localstorage)

```
useEffect(() => {
  function checkUserData() {
    const item = localStorage.getItem('userData')

    if (item) {
      setUserData(item)
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('storage', checkUserData)

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('storage', checkUserData)
  }
}, [])
```

But again, it didn't seem to "catch" change of localStorage variable.

2. I tried to export "open" variable:

   ```
    export const TabsMobile: FC<ITabsMobile> = ({
      //...
      openExternal,
      setOpenexternal
    }) => {
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
   ```

But again, how to access it externally and make the "AdditionalMobile" appear/hide depending on it?

Comment: hey it would be good if u can move this to a gist and is it possible to provide a screen share or screen shot of how u want functionality to look like, btw as per u implementation currently u lack the ability to listen for local storage changes right? to overcome this u can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/broadcast-channel to listen and post messages and do your action based on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround. Maybe not too smart, but it does resolve the issue.
I will post it here for others:

The problem is, that something must be triggered in main file, so the new value of "mainTabOpen" item from "localStorage".

What I did - in addition to "onClick" event **inside** the element - in element function, I also placed another outside of it in main file.

In element file:

```
  function updateOpen()
  {
      var openString : string = !open == true ? "true" : "false";      
      localStorage.setItem("mainTabOpen", openString);
      setOpen(!open);
  }
```

In main file:

```
        <div onClick={() =>  resetVisibility()}>
          <TabsMobile
            TabsArray={TabsTransactionsArray}
            tab={tab}
            setTab={setTab}
            setPages={setPages}           
          />   
        </div>  

  function resetVisibility()
  {
     setMainTabOpen(localStorage.getItem("mainTabOpen") == "true" ? true : false);
     console.log('Outside: '+mainTabOpen);
  }

{!mainTabOpen && <AdditionalMobile/>}
```

I already have "**useEffect**" in main file, so I didn't have to add a new one, but if someone uses this approach, they might need it.

**Why I just don't change the value in main file?**
Because if I do this, the value will be changed not only when clicking on "show tabs" button, but also when changing a tab.

For example (icons element appear when "show tabs is False)":

- Starting value: false
- I click on 'show tabs" to show it, value: true
- I click on tab I select, value: false
- I click on 'show tabs" to hide it, value: false

**As result "icons" element is hidden, while should be visible.**

Event "onClick" assigned to "**div**" surrounding the button will trigger not only on "show tabs" button is clicked, **but also when buttons of specific tab (children of "show tabs") are used**.

Event "**onClick**" assigned to element, will trigger **only when "show tabs" button is clicked**.

**Because of it, the actual value of "mainTabOpen" must be changed when clicking on button "show tabs" itself, in the element function, and not in main file function.**